# How to explain intuitively to a lay audience that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator?

Tags: variance, intuition, unbiased-estimator, communication

I have data for the concentration of several chemicals in the milk of 10000 cows and have to explain to policymakers and the lay public (i.e. people with no or limited knowledge of statistics) that the variance calculated from our sample is an unbiased indicator of the variance in chemicals' concentration in the population.

Call it professional deformation but I am having a hard time coming with an accessible explanation. What is an intuitive way to explain that the variance is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: Not trying to be facetious, but why do you need to explain it at all? For a start  it's the standard deviation that is more likely to make substantive sense here. But then the usual estimator of the SD (with sample size $-$ 1 inside, not sample size, which I think you're alluding to) is not strictly unbiased. Generations of scientists and even some statisticians have muddled through without knowing or fully understanding that.

Comment: In addition to Nick's approach I would say to the audience that if the concentration distribution is symmetric and not too heavy tailed, the sample SD is a good estimate of the concentration population's dispersion when you have at least 70 samples.  (n=70 gives a multiplicative margin of error in estimating $\sigma$ of 1.2 with confidence level 0.95).

Comment: @Frank That's an interesting claim about the margin of error, but it must depend on some extra assumptions.  What are they?  Normality of the DGP?

Comment: Yes that actually assumes normality.  Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: There's a reasonably intuitive explanation of why the n-denominator version of variance is biased (and that you need to divide by something smaller than n), but the nearest I can get to a nonmathematical explanation of unbiasedness with n-1 would involve talking about the average squared difference between pairs of observations. However, you also need to relate that quantity back to the variance and it ends up using more mathematics than I expect you want. But why would unbiasedness of the *variance* be what you care about? The standard deviation is biased downward.

Comment: But if relevant sample size is 1000, the downward bias of the sample standard deviation is negligible.

Answer (score 6):

It is rather odd that you would need to explain the concept of unbiasedness to a lay audience at all.  If they are not already familiar with the idea of an "expected value", and some other general ideas in sampling theory, then what exactly is the necessity in distinguishing a biased from an unbiased estimator?  Will you also explain consistency of the estimator, etc.?

A far more important explanatory and interpretive problem I see here is specifying *what you mean* by "the population" and how you sampled from this population.  What set of cows (larger than your sample of 10,000 cows) is "the population" here?  Did you use simple random sampling from this population, or some other sampling method?  Are you absolutely sure that your sampling method does not induce bias?

In any case, if you really do need to give an explanation of the concept of an "unbiased" estimator to a lay audience, something like this would not butcher the concept too much:

> We have estimated the variance in the population for our analysis, which was [specified set of cows].  We estimated the variance of the concentration of chemicals in these cows using something that statisticians call an "unbiased estimator".  Roughly speaking, this means that our estimate of the variance will ---on average--- be equal to the true variance in the population.

Comment: I agree that emphasis should be on the margins of error, not on bias.

Comment: @Ben makes a great point, and his reasoning is exactly why a Bayesian approach to the problem makes more sense.  We are interested in recovering the data generating process, whether that process generated only this one dataset or could possibly generate a sequence of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right verb is not *explain* but to *convince* here. In order for the sample variance to be an unbiased estimator the population variance certain conditions to be held. For instance, if your sample was a truly random sample from the population you could make this argument. Hence, it's on you to convince your audience that your sample is a random sample. In empirical research there are all kinds of issues with sampling biases to deal with. Therefore, it's perfectly reasonable to question unbiasedness of your estimator for anyone consuming your research results.